# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: in training of U-Net

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I would like to ask for help in resolving an error I encounter when starting the training of my U-Net. My network aims to detect objects. My model has 2218 training images and 50 test images. All images are accompanied by their masks in different directories. The images are balanced in both the training and test sets, with an equal number of images containing and not containing nodules (half with nodules and half without nodules).

For those who want to reproduce the error, here is a copy of the notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1D60Ve_4LlpViPsiaT6S935HTjxruiMQo?usp=sharing

Here is a copy of the data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vo7frsJ3EMa_OFinoh7sPFsBpJFTD0-m?usp=sharing

This is the error:

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5239c1cdf89c> in <cell line: 76>()
     74 
     75 # Training the model using the train_generator
---> 76 history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=EPOCHS,
     77                     callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(test_images, test_masks),
     78                     validation_steps=validation_steps)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58         for t in inputs
     59     ]
---> 60     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     61                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     62   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node mul_1 defined at (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/colab_kernel_launcher.py", line 37, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 992, in launch_instance

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 619, in start

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once

  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 685, in <lambda>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 738, in _run_callback

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 825, in inner

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 377, in dispatch_queue

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 250, in wrapper

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 748, in __init__

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 786, in run

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 361, in process_one

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 261, in dispatch_shell

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 539, in execute_request

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 302, in do_execute

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 539, in run_cell

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2975, in run_cell

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3030, in _run_cell

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3257, in run_cell_async

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3473, in run_ast_nodes

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code

  File "<ipython-input-9-5239c1cdf89c>", line 76, in <cell line: 76>

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1783, in fit

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1377, in train_function

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1360, in step_function

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1349, in run_step

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1131, in train_step

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1225, in compute_metrics

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 620, in update_state

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/metrics/base_metric.py", line 723, in update_state

  File "<ipython-input-6-16eec044ce63>", line 16, in iou

required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node mul_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_6791]
```

And here is the full code of the model for those who dislike Google Colab:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import save_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization, Dropout, Lambda, Conv2DTranspose, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Concatenate
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Metric
import tensorflow
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import AUC
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score, jaccard_score, average_precision_score
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks


# Defina os diretórios dos dados de treinamento e teste
diretorio_treinamento_imagens = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/imagens_mascaras/train/'
diretorio_treinamento_mascaras = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/imagens_mascaras/train_masks/'
diretorio_teste_imagens = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/imagens_mascaras/test/'
diretorio_teste_mascaras = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Node21/imagens_mascaras/test_masks/'

# Função para carregar imagens e máscaras
def carregar_imagens_mascaras(diretorio_imagens, diretorio_mascaras):
    imagens = []
    mascaras = []

    for filename in os.listdir(diretorio_imagens):
        if filename.endswith(".png"):
            # Carregar imagem
            imagem = cv2.imread(os.path.join(diretorio_imagens, filename), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            imagens.append(imagem)

            # Carregar máscara correspondente
            mascara_nome = filename.replace(".png", "_mask.png")
            mascara = cv2.imread(os.path.join(diretorio_mascaras, mascara_nome), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            mascaras.append(mascara)

    return imagens, mascaras

# Carregar imagens de treinamento e suas máscaras
imagens_treinamento, mascaras_treinamento = carregar_imagens_mascaras(diretorio_treinamento_imagens, diretorio_treinamento_mascaras)

# Carregar imagens de teste e suas máscaras
imagens_teste, mascaras_teste = carregar_imagens_mascaras(diretorio_teste_imagens, diretorio_teste_mascaras)

# Converter listas de imagens e máscaras para arrays NumPy
imagens_treinamento = np.array(imagens_treinamento)
mascaras_treinamento = np.array(mascaras_treinamento)
imagens_teste = np.array(imagens_teste)
mascaras_teste = np.array(mascaras_teste)

# Verificar o formato das imagens e máscaras
print("Formato das imagens de treinamento:", imagens_treinamento.shape)
print("Formato das máscaras de treinamento:", mascaras_treinamento.shape)
print("Formato das imagens de teste:", imagens_teste.shape)
print("Formato das máscaras de teste:", mascaras_teste.shape)


smooth = 1.0

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_truef = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_predf = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_truef * y_predf)
    return (2.0 * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_truef) + K.sum(y_predf) + smooth)

def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_truef = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_predf = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_truef * y_predf)
    return 1.0 - (2.0 * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_truef) + K.sum(y_predf) + smooth)

def iou(y_true, y_pred):
    intersection = K.sum(y_true * y_pred)
    union = K.sum(K.maximum(y_true, y_pred))
    jac = (intersection + smooth) / (union + smooth)
    return jac

def jac_distance(y_true, y_pred):
    return -iou(y_true, y_pred)

print()


def unet_with_batch_norm(input_shape=(512, 512, 1), dropout_rate=0.3, learning_rate=0.001):
    inputs = Input(input_shape)

    # Parte de codificação (downsampling)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    bn1 = BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(bn1)
    pool1 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(pool1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    bn2 = BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(bn2)
    pool2 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(pool2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    bn3 = BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3))(bn3)
    pool3 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(pool3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    bn4 = BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4))(bn4)
    pool4 = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(pool4)

    # Parte de decodificação (upsampling)
    up6 = UpSampling2D(size=(4, 4))(pool4)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up6)
    conv6 = Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)
    bn6 = BatchNormalization()(conv6)

    up7 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(bn6)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up7)
    conv7 = Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
    bn7 = BatchNormalization()(conv7)

    up8 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(bn7)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up8)
    conv8 = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)
    bn8 = BatchNormalization()(conv8)

    up9 = UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(bn8)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(up9)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)
    bn9 = BatchNormalization()(conv9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(bn9)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=['accuracy', iou, dice_coef])

    return model

model = unet_with_batch_norm()

# Visualização da arquitetura da U-Net
model.summary()


import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Carregar imagens de treinamento e suas máscaras
imagens_treinamento, mascaras_treinamento = carregar_imagens_mascaras(diretorio_treinamento_imagens, diretorio_treinamento_mascaras)

# Carregar imagens de teste e suas máscaras
imagens_teste, mascaras_teste = carregar_imagens_mascaras(diretorio_teste_imagens, diretorio_teste_mascaras)

# Certifique-se de que as imagens e máscaras tenham a mesma resolução (512x512)
im_height, im_width = 512, 512
imagens_treinamento = [cv2.resize(img, (im_width, im_height)) for img in imagens_treinamento]
mascaras_treinamento = [cv2.resize(mask, (im_width, im_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST) for mask in mascaras_treinamento]
imagens_teste = [cv2.resize(img, (im_width, im_height)) for img in imagens_teste]
mascaras_teste = [cv2.resize(mask, (im_width, im_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST) for mask in mascaras_teste]

# Converter listas de imagens e máscaras para arrays NumPy
imagens_treinamento = np.array(imagens_treinamento)
mascaras_treinamento = np.array(mascaras_treinamento)
imagens_teste = np.array(imagens_teste)
mascaras_teste = np.array(mascaras_teste)

# Verificar o formato das imagens e máscaras
print("Formato das imagens de treinamento:", imagens_treinamento.shape)
print("Formato das máscaras de treinamento:", mascaras_treinamento.shape)
print("Formato das imagens de teste:", imagens_teste.shape)
print("Formato das máscaras de teste:", mascaras_teste.shape)


from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
import tensorflow as tf

# Definindo transformações de imagem para o gerador de dados
data_gen_args = dict(
    rotation_range=0.2,
    width_shift_range=0.05,
    height_shift_range=0.05,
    shear_range=0.05,
    zoom_range=0.05,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

im_height = 512
im_width = 512
BATCH_SIZE = 8
EPOCHS = 100

# Ajuste o diretório de saída para as imagens aumentadas, se necessário
output_dir = '/content/train_aug/'

# Garanta que o diretório de saída exista
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

# Adicione uma dimensão extra para o canal de cores (escala de cinza)
imagens_treinamento = np.expand_dims(imagens_treinamento, axis=-1)
mascaras_treinamento = np.expand_dims(mascaras_treinamento, axis=-1)

# Criando geradores de dados a partir das matrizes
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

seed = 1  # Semente aleatória para garantir correspondência entre imagens e máscaras

# Criando geradores de treinamento e teste
image_generator = image_datagen.flow(imagens_treinamento, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(mascaras_treinamento, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=seed)
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)

# Adicione uma dimensão extra para o canal de cores (escala de cinza)
#imagens_teste = np.expand_dims(imagens_teste, axis=-1)
#mascaras_teste = np.expand_dims(mascaras_teste, axis=-1)

# Criando geradores de dados de teste (sem aumento de dados)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

# Crie geradores de dados a partir das matrizes, sem adicionar uma dimensão extra
image_generator = image_datagen.flow(imagens_treinamento, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=seed)
mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(mascaras_treinamento, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, seed=seed)

#test_gener = zip(test_image_generator, test_mask_generator)

# Adicione uma dimensão extra para o canal de cores (escala de cinza) apenas ao definir o modelo
model = unet_with_batch_norm(input_shape=(im_height, im_width, 1))

# Defining the optimizer
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

# Setting callbacks
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, mode='min', verbose=1)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('unet_lung_nodule_detection.hdf5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
callbacks = [model_checkpoint, early_stop]

# Calculating the number of steps per epoch and validation steps
steps_per_epoch = len(imagens_treinamento) // BATCH_SIZE
validation_steps = len(imagens_teste) // BATCH_SIZE

# Compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=["binary_accuracy", iou, dice_coef])

# Training the model using the train_generator
history = model.fit(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, epochs=EPOCHS,
                    callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(imagens_teste, mascaras_teste),
                    validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible try can be:

Change

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam
```